# htaccess 301 redirect https to https and http to http

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I've seen lots of questions about http to https and https to http redirects, but nothing about redirecting all traffic, both http and https to a new site.

Here's what my htaccess file looks like, but it is not working. How can I redirect https requests to https://www.mynewsite.com/ and http requests to http://www.mynewsite.com/ ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mynewsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mynewsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The rewrite rule attached to the second condition always fires; the first one never fires. "https ://www.oldsite.com" and "http ://www.oldsite.com" always 301 to "http ://www.newsite.com/" and never to the https site

Comment: If you remove this .htaccess and enter `https://example.com`, does it show same content as `http://example.com`?

Comment: Yes, it does show the same information.

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish redirecting http and https requests to the new site respectively.  HTTP to HTTP and HTTPS to HTTPS, just from the old URL to the new one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.mynewsite.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.mynewsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```